# How to add delete icon on each line on Kendo grids

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

i am busy trying to modify the existing Kendo grid. I want to add small delete/remove icon button on Kendo grid. the delete/remove will appear in each and every line. When i click delete/remove icon button, it must delete that specific line(this button will just deactivate it not permanently delete it).

Here is my code below:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
var data = (DetailsModel)ViewData["GridData"];

var dataList = data.pricing;
var detailsId = ViewData["DetailsID"];
}
```

---

```
     <div class="form-group">
                                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(dataList)
                            .Name("MyGrid")
                            .Columns(column =>
                            {
                                column.Bound(c => c.PartId).Width("70px").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "vertical-align:top !important;" }).FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });
                                column.Bound(c => c.GMarkPartNumber)

                                .Title("GMMNo").Width("90px").FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });
                                column.Bound(c => c.Description).FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });

                                column.Group(grp => grp
                                .Title("Price")
                                .Columns(info =>
                                {
                                    info.Bound(x => x.Price).FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });
                                    info.Bound(x => x.Fitting).FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });
                                    info.Bound(x => x.Extras).FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });
                                    info.Bound(x => x.VAT).FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });
                                    info.Bound(x => x.TotalInc).FooterTemplate("<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-md-4 pull-right\"><div class=\"pull-right\">" +
                                        "<table><tr><td class=\"formatFooter\">Total Exclusive:</td><td class=\"formatFooter\">R" + data.totalExclusive + "</td></tr>"
                                            + "<tr><td class=\"formatFooter\">Total VAT:</td><td class=\"formatFooter\">R" + data.totalVat + "</td></tr>"
                                            + "<tr><td class=\"formatFooter\">Total Inclusive:</td><td class=\"formatFooter\">R" + data.totalInclusive + "</td></tr></table></div></div></div>")
                                            .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { colspan = 8 });

                                }));

                            })
                                .Groupable()
                                .Scrollable()
                                .Sortable()
                                    )
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use ClientTemplate for this. Bound a column for delete and specify the html of the button inside ClientTemplate()

```
columns.Template(t => t.Column).HeaderTemplate("").ClientTemplate(@"<a href='javascript: void(0)' class='btn btnDelete' onclick='onDelete(#= Id #)' title='button delete'>" + Delete +" </a>").Title("");
```

Comment: It Delete says it doesn't exist? Can you also please help me with the java-script?